# Can I drill holes in septic tank risers to off-gas hydrogen sulfide?

Tags: septic

How about drilling a few small vent holes in the riser (assuming it is open air and not buried)? The septic guy says that doing so would vent the HS gas and significantly extend the life of the second stage tank (the first tak is vented through the house plumbing).

Answer (score 2):

Both tanks (in fact, the whole system) should be designed to vent gases back through the house vent stack. Drilling holes in the "riser" (are you calling the inspection port/manhole the riser?) will release the gas there and cause odor at that area. It could also expose an innocent passer-by to poisonous H2S gas.

I would be careful following this guy's advice. If the system required additional venting it would have been designed and installed to provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that won't work for one simple reason.
Hydrogen sulfide is "heavier than air". It rolls downhill and is dispersed into the soil of the drainfield.
https://www.onsiteinstaller.com/editorial/2011/05/why_do_they_break_down

Only methane is actually vented up through the building venting system, because it is "lighter than air".